# Displaying information read in from a json file - android

Tags: android, json

I have the following (and more, but it's only some of it) code in a json file in the raw folder in my project.

```
{
"Monday": [
    {
        "time": "09:15",
        "class": "Nature",
        "room": "AL32"
    },
    {
        "time": "10:15",
        "class": "Nature",
        "room": "AL32"
    }
],
"Tuesday": [
    {
        "time": "12:15",
        "class": "Maths",
        "room": "AL20"
    },
    {
        "time": "13:15",
        "class": "Englsh",
        "room": "AG22"
    }
]....etc

}
```

I want it displayed like

```
Time|Class|Room
Monday
09:15|Nature|AL32
10:15|Nature|AL32
Tuesday
12:15|Maths|AL20
13:15|English|AG22
etc etc
```

What I have done (so far) is, read in the information in the json file with
BufferedReader jsonReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.localjsonfile)));

Then I can print out everything (to the LogCat) in the file with

```
String readLine = null;
// While the BufferedReader readLine is not null 
while ((readLine = jsonReader.readLine()) != null) 
{
    System.out.println(readLine);
}
```

but I don't know where to go from there. I'm thinking I store anything in Monday in an array/object called monday (and Tuesday in an array/object called tuesday etc) and then print out the values in the arrays/objects and put them in the TextView fields that I have (I have three textviews called android:id="@+id/time", android:id="@+id/class and android:id="@+id/room") and then the textviews will be reprinted to the screen as needed.

I have only started learning android and java and I know nothing about json, so I'm stuck on how to go any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for getting JSON from a row folder and parsing.

```
 //Get Data From Text Resource File Contains Json Data.

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.localjsonfile);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int ctr;
        try {
            ctr = inputStream.read();
            while (ctr != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(ctr);
                ctr = inputStream.read();
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("Text Data", byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
        try {

            // Parse the data into jsonobject to get original data in form of json.  
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(
                    byteArrayOutputStream.toString());

            JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("Monday");
            String  time="";
            String class ="";
            String room ="";

            ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                time= jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("time");
                class= jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("class");
                 room= jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("room");

                data.add(new String[] {time, class,room});
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

look at this [library](http://www.json.org/java/) for help with JSON parsing,
For more examples of JSON Parsing read [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html)

Comment: Thanks, the above code does work, but I had to change "jObjectResult" to "jObject" and class to module otherwise there was errors. I have gotten the time, class and room to print out to the screen by using    TextView tv0 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
tv0.setText(time);
But this only prints the 'time' once. I'm not sure how to get it to print out more than one row. I'm thinking I somehow set it so for each row in the data array a row is returned to the screen.